# LibreOffice 5 : 2 x Different Toolbar Icon Sets - Same Config - Ubuntu 16.04 Gnome Flashback

Tags: 16.04, gnome, libreoffice, gui

**ISSUE**

I get 2 different LibreOffice Toolbar Icon Sets on 2 laptops with basically the same Ubuntu 16.04 installation:

**UI 1 - Slick & fresh**

[image]

**UI 2 - Chunky & dated**

[image]

**INSTALL**

Both laptops installed from scratch:

- Install from Live CD
- Wiped partition tables
- Ubuntu boot only
- **Ubuntu 16.04**
- **Gnome Flashback**
- **LibreOffice 5**

Both built in the last 10 days:

- Same install CD
- Same install process
- Same config process

When I first fired up LibreOffice Calc, I thought that the interface looked a bit "not so great".

After:

- running a sudo apt-get update
- adding a couple of unrelated other packages
- on my next load of calc things looked slicker

I'd love to replicate the slick look on my second machine ... but I am having a WTF moment, searching around in circles, and getting nowhere.

**QUESTION**

What is causing the difference ?

How do I get the second install looking great ?

Would be most grateful for any advice.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A big thank you to **danielnl** on *#libreoffice* for online assistance.

I have posted his helful advice here to close my own question

Here is the (somewhat trivial) solution:

There are user preference choices available for **Icon size and style**

[ Tools ]
-> [ Options ]
-> [ View ]
-> [ User Interface ]
-> [ Icon size and style ]

-> [ selectionbox#2 ]

- **Automatic (Galaxy)**

  - shows my reference above to **UI 2 - Chunky & dated**
- **Breeze**

  - shows my reference above to **UI 1 - Slick & fresh**

---

Here is a pretty useful help page with screenshots for installing and setting more Icon Sets:

http://www.debugpoint.com/2016/08/quick-tip-change-the-default-libreoffice-look-and-feel/

That gives quite a few options, but I like the slick minimal Breezy.